# Mapping name from .txt to a folder in java

Tags: java

I have a folder called attachment which contains 5 .gif images and i have a att.txt which contains name for this .gif images, Now i need to rename these images with the name present in att.txt.
Below is the code i tried.Please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\template_export\\template\\attachments"));
    String sCurrentLine="";
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
         sCurrentLine= sCurrentLine.replaceAll("txt", "gif");
         String[] s = sCurrentLine.split(",");
         for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
             new File("D:\\template_export\\template\\attachment_new"+s[i]).mkdirs();
             System.out.println("Folder Created");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: providing the content of `att.txt` would be helpful

Comment: /enumeration/blocker.gif
/enumeration/critical.gif
/workflow/close.gif
/workflow/defer.gif .......... I need a folder for 1st three types and it should the images from the attachment folder.
/workitemtype/bug.gif
/workitemtype/enhancement.gif
process_template_license.html
template.messages
template_en_US.messages

Comment: At present code, its not taking the images from the attachment folder

Comment: is this `att.txt` in same folder where all these `.gif` files are located. also `/enumeration/blocker.gif` means we need to place it in `enumeration` folder. Please rephrase your question for clearance.

Comment: Why are you calling `readLine` on a folder?

Comment: this is my D:\template_export\template\attachments path where all images are present in form of numbers 0.gif,1.gif,2.gif etc & D:\template_export\template\attachments.txt path where names for 0.gif , 1.gif are present. we can create a new folder called attachments_new which contains C:\Users\Desktop\MyTask\demo\attachments_new\enumeration\bloker.gif.C:\Users\Desktop\MyTask\demo\attachments_new\workflow\.C:\Users\Desktop\MyTask\demo\attachments_new\workitemtype\.

Comment: how is the `attachments.txt` formatted ? Is every image name on its own line or could there be multiple names on the same line ?

Comment: /enumeration/blocker.gif
/enumeration/critical.gif
/workflow/close.gif
/workflow/defer.gif
/workitemtype/bug.gif
/workitemtype/enhancement.gif
process_template_license.html
template.messages
template_en_US.messages............this is how the format of attachments.txt... 0.gif,1.gif,2.gif are in sorted.i just need to map these

Comment: @geetha you were saying that there are 5 images, but 6 names are provided in file?

Comment: Yes... first will be the folder name and rest will be the .gif images inside these folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Tst {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File orgDirectory = new File("attachements");// replace this filename 
                                                 // with the path to the folder 
                                                 // that contains the original images

    String fileContent = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(orgDirectory, "attachements.txt")))) {
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            fileContent += line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] newLocations = fileContent.split(" ");
    File[] orgFiles = orgDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getPath().endsWith(".gif");
        }
    });
    File destinationFolder = new File("processed");
    int max = Math.min(orgFiles.length, newLocations.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        String newLocation = newLocations[i];
        int lastIndex = newLocation.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (lastIndex == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        String newDirName = newLocation.substring(0, lastIndex);
        String newName = newLocation.substring(lastIndex);
        File newDir = new File(destinationFolder, newDirName);
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            newDir.mkdir();
        }
        try {
            Files.move(orgFiles[i].toPath(), new File(newDir, newName).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

It probably won't work since your description isn't that clear but I hope you get the idea and you understand how this task can be done. The important parts are:

```
File[] orgFiles = orgDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getPath().endsWith(".gif");
        }
 });
```

Which creates a `File` array which contains all the "gif" files in the source directory.

And:

```
Files.move(orgFiles[i].toPath(), new File(newDir, newName).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Which mover the original image to the new directory and sets its name to the one retrieved from the "attachements.txt" file.

Comment: Hi Titus, i got below error...........java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\template_export\template\attachments\0.gif -> processed\enumeration\blocker.gif\enumeration\critical.gif\enumeration\high.gif\enumeration\low.gif\enumeration\major.gif\enumeration\medium.gif\enumeration\minor.gif\enumeration\normal.gif\enumeration\unassigned.gif\enumeration\unassigned2.gif\workflow\close.gif\workflow\defer.gif\workflow\duplicate.gif\workflow\inprogress.gif\workflow\new.gif\workflow\open.gif\workflow\reject.gif\workflow\remind.gif\workflow\reopen.gif\workflow\resolve.gif\workflow\unconfigure.gif\workfl

Comment: @geetha That is probably because the "attachements.txt" doesn't have the format that I've thought it has (multiple file paths separated by a single space). I don't have enough info to fix that, try to understand the code and modify it to work for you.